# All keyboard events for my NSTableView are disabled

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

All keyboard events for my NSTableView are disabled. I can't use arrows or select a row with space bar.

The NSTAbleView belongs to a NSPanel, which is the current key Window, and the NSTableView is the first responder of the panel:

```
print (int) [self isKeyWindow] $1 = 1

po [self firstResponder] <NSTableView: 0xa7c6cc0>
```

If I remove the table from my panel (and also the other table) the ESC button works again. I guess something is wrong with the table event handling.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table view has lost its first responder status. Do you have any other controls in the window that are responding to key events? Try setting your window's intital first responder, making other controls refuse first responder, setting up your `nextKeyView` paths, or manually setting the table as the first responder by calling `[window makeFirstResponder:tableView]`.

First responder issues can be a PITA, but if you read the documentation and go through your code with logging statements you can get an idea of where those key events are going.

Comment: I don't get is, my panel is the keyWindow and the table is the firstResponder: print (int) [self isKeyWindow]
$1 = 1, po [self firstResponder]
<NSTableView: 0xa7c6cc0>

Comment: Actually the panel doesn't answer to the ESC event, but if I remove the table from the nib file (and also the other table), than it works again.

Comment: Thanks, you gave me my first clue... but my NSTableView is placed within a ClipView and scrollers, and a ScrollView which is inside of  a vertical NSStackView... how can I make sense of any of this?